# Rails & ActiveRecord complex query: rendering a collection of has_many through objects while substituting one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a List model. A List has_many :lists_movies and has_many :movies through :lists_movies and has_many :trailers through :movies.  ListsMovie has a list_id, movie_id, and title columns.

I want to render all the trailers of movies in a given list, populating all the trailer data AND the list_movie.title. What is the best way to accomplish this?

If I *just* wanted to render the trailers, I could go:

```
@trailers = @list.trailers

@trailers.each do |t|
 t.description
 t.youtube_id
end
```

But I also want the title from the list_movie like:

```
@trailers.each do |t|
     list_movie.title
     t.description
     t.youtube_id
    end
```

Basically I'm trying to iterate and get data from 2 different objects.. but having trouble on which collections I should be loading.

Comment: I don't actually understand the associations by reading. It would be great if you could post the **models**. But won't `t.movie.list_movie.title` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing out the query in English: "For each list, I want to write down the list_movie title, and each trailer for that movie", which, in ruby, now easily translates to:

```
@list.lists_movies.each do |list_movie|
  # list_movie.title
  list_movie.movie.trailers.each do |trailer|
    # trailer.description
    # trailer.youtube_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, that's great advice. Makes a lot of sense when you write it out like that.